# Drupal - Taxonomy translated terms disappear after running cron

Tags: drupal, translation, drupal-taxonomy

I am having a curious problem in Drupal 7, related to Taxonomy translation.

I am using a taxonomy vocabulary whose terms are localized. In order to differ taxonomy terms from one another (so the term names can all have different names), I am using an extra field called "Display Name". Since I have to show the names of the taxonomy terms and some of them have the same name (and I already had problems with that), I opted for using this extra field. And I found out that I can enable translation for this field only, through an option named "Enable Translation" in field settings.

Then, I have translated these terms using this option named "Enable Translation". I found that it is a batch operation that is activated when you enable it, allowing you to set up translated terms via the interface provided by Taxonomy.

However, after updating the website, I found out that my terms using this "Display Name" field disappeared. And I can't seem to find the problem... It doesn't seem like something is missing in my feature but, since it is a batch operation, it will only be effective in the environment this batch is executed, right?

Maybe this already happened to someone else but, after a thorough research, I have found no valuable information about it. I appreciate any help you may provide!